# Fading multiple elements simultaneously - jquery

Tags: jquery, fade

I want to do the following:

```
$(newPanel, prevBtn, nextBtn, infoPanel).fadeIn(200, function() {
}
```

these vars are divs created with jquery

but only the first element fades in, I really need all elements to fade in at the same time.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the `add` method to get the elements in the same jQuery object:

```
newPanel.add(prevBtn).add(nextBtn).add(infoPanel).fadeIn(200);
```

Comment: Ahhh, that's quite nice. Will try that next time.

Comment: @Guffa I added a callback and the callback is executed four times. Is this normal with any grouping?

Comment: @Wesley: As you have four elements in the jQuery object, each animation gets its own callback. From the docs: "If multiple elements are animated, it is important to note that the callback is executed once per matched element, not once for the animation as a whole." http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Comment: @Guffa Suppose to have an array of jQuery objects, can you add them in a for cycle to `newPanel`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @jonny_cage: Yes, you can use the add method to concatenate jQuery objects. If you can make it an array of elements instead of jQuery objects, you can use a single add call.

Comment: @Guffa. Thanks for the answer. Could you make a brief example?

Comment: @jonny_cage: Where `j` is the jQuery object and `arr` is the array of jQuery objects to add to it: `for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) j = j.add(arr[i]);`

Comment: Ah ok! I understood that you can add the whole array to add. Now it is clear. Thanks.

Comment: Does this work with IE? I am using this line of code and IE fade out animation doesn't start: `$('#yellow').add($("#sine")).animate({opacity: '0'}, function() { .. } ...`

Comment: Seems IE has problems with fadeOut animation .. ty for quick answer .. googling already :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `newPanel` and so on are variables created like that:

```
newPanel = $("#newPanel");
```

just write:

```
newPanel.fadeIn(200);
prevBtn.fadeIn(200);
nextBtn.fadeIn(200);
infoPanel.fadeIn(200);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each([newPanel, prevBtn, nextBtn, infoPanel], function(i, el) {
    $(el).fadeIn(200);
});
```

**update:**
And if you want to call the function only once, you could do something [like @Guffa did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952556/fading-multiple-elements-simutaneously-jquery/6952616#6952629) by adding the elements to the same jQuery collection and only then apply the animation (once):

```
[newPanel, prevBtn, nextBtn, infoPanel]
    .reduce(function(el, next) {
        return el.add(next);
    })
    .fadeIn(200);
```

Comment: Won't this be the same as doing them one at a time?

Answer (score 0):

Either do it using a `$.each` call or I would recommend that you group them by a class or id and fade using that.

You could for example group all related elements in classes and then do a `$.each` call on those classes instead of every single element.

Comment: If I add a callback, will that be executed for each element that has the class? I just want a callback called once. @inquam

Comment: You mean if you have a callback to be called when the animation has finished will it trigger once for the entire collection of elements using the class or once for every element using the class? I actually don't know by heart. I would guess that it would trigger once for every element though since I think it get's attached onto each element. This could be overcome by adding a check if the callback has already been called once. Something like `if(!firsttime) return;`. Perhaps not the prettiest thing in the world but it would work.